# How to create a Light/Dark function in a toggle button

Tags: javascript, html, css, togglebutton

I have made a light/dark toggle button and I want to add light/dark function to that. The page should toggle its theme between dark and light modes on the press of this switch. Some basic styling is added to the switch to make it show a light or dark theme on toggling it.

```html
<body>
  <div class="theme-toggle" style="cursor: pointer;">
    <input type="checkbox" checked style="cursor: pointer;">
    <div class="toggle-body" style="cursor: pointer;"></div>
    <div class="celestial-body" style="cursor: pointer;"></div>
  </div>
  <style>
     :root {
      --width: 60px;
      --height: 30px;
    }
    
    body {
      font-family: monaco, sans-serif;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 2em;
    }
    
    .theme-toggle {
      position: relative;
      width: var(--width);
      height: var(--height);
    }
    
    .theme-toggle input[type="checkbox"] {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      opacity: 0;
      z-index: 1;
      width: var(--width);
      height: var(--height);
    }
    
    .theme-toggle .toggle-body {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: var(--width);
      height: var(--height);
      border: 2px solid #080808;
      border-radius: var(--height);
      transition: all 80ms ease-in-out;
    }
    
    .theme-toggle input[type="checkbox"]~.toggle-body {
      background: #1d1d1d;
      background-image: url("https://cdn.glitch.com/9be3ef5e-cf68-4fac-9bd5-82714468aed6%2F1e7b6b11b5b398711c60f2b71cdf9b03.gif?v=1599237363310");
      background-size: cover;
    }
    /*
        https://i.giphy.com/media/U3qYN8S0j3bpK/giphy.webp
        */
    
    .theme-toggle input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.toggle-body {
      background: #82dfff/*#EDBCD4*/
      ;
      background-image: url("");
      background-size: cover;
      border-color: #89cbf9/*#CAAAB7*/
      ;
    }
    /*
        https://i.giphy.com/media/tQgB6lM6XCle8/giphy.webp
        */
    
    .theme-toggle input[type="checkbox"]~.celestial-body {
      position: absolute;
      width: 24px;
      height: 24px;
      border: 2px solid #fff08e/*white*/
      ;
      border-radius: 100%;
      background: #fff5c4/*#F0F0FA*/
      ;
      transition: all 80ms ease-in-out;
    }
    
    .theme-toggle input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)~.celestial-body {
      top: 3px;
      left: 3px;
    }
    
    .theme-toggle input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.celestial-body {
      top: 3px;
      left: calc(100% - 27px);
      background: #ff9900/*#F2E9BD*/
      ;
      border-color: #ddceb1;
    }
    
    .theme-toggle input[type="checkbox"]~.celestial-body::after {
      content: " ";
      opacity: 0;
      position: absolute;
      left: -20px;
      transition: left 0.13s ease-in, opacity 0.15s ease-out;
    }
    
    .theme-toggle input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.celestial-body::after {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      bottom: -2px;
      left: -10px;
      display: block;
      opacity: 1;
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
      background: url("https://cdn.glitch.com/9be3ef5e-cf68-4fac-9bd5-82714468aed6%2FVector%201%20(1).svg?v=1599249814204");
      background-size: contain;
      background-position: left;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
  </style>
</body>
```

You can see this code also on the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Coders_Champ/c5z9tgrf/)
The light/dark function I am using for my website that `onclick()` changes to light/dark mode.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `:root` colors for change mode,

when you click on button, change `:root` colors

[See Document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/addRule)